# Centos8, run gtk program under sudo privileges: cannot open display: :0

Tags: centos, sudo, gnome, gtk

I'm currently struggling when trying to run `bleachbit` under root privileges on `CentOS 8`.
Using my `non-sudo` user, there is no problem. When i try to run it as sudo, i get the following error:

```
(bleachbit.py:10145): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 10:04:10.493: gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(bleachbit.py:10145): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:04:10.503: cannot open display: :0
```

The problem seems related to the lack of `gksudo`.

Does someone know how to run a `gtk` tool under `sudo` privileges?

## EDIT

A solution seems to be type the following command on terminal.

```bsh
xhost +
```

Comment: At least type `xhost` without parameters before you type `xhost +` to see what is open. `xhost +` opens up everything, which is too much. I think it is enough to open access for root user. Try typing `xhost +SI:localuser:root`.

Comment: Maybe it would solve your problem for good if you put `localhost` in `/etc/X0.hosts`. You would need to test it as I am not sure about that. Take a look here: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/GECG/X_Disp_ProcAccessByHost.html

Comment: Write as a response please, so i can confirm the solution sir :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open access to your X session by issuing `xhost` command. First type

```
xhost
```

to see what is open. Then, in your case, you should probably type

```
xhost +SI:localuser:root
```

To open all connections from localhost permanently I think you should add

```
localhost
```

to `etc/X0.hosts`. Take a look here for more info: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/GECG/X_Disp_ProcAccessByHost.html